# How to add jquery .not() in a div inside the body when the body is the one being affected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
     $('#button').click(function(){
       $('body').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(4px)');
     });
```

When button is clicked, body is turned blur, but i don't want the div inside the body to turn blurred as well. How to do that? can i do that with the .not() jquery function?

Answer (score 3):

No, the `not([selector])` function is used for discarding elements from the current jQuery selection. It can't be used for exempting an element from an effect that is applied to one of its ancestor elements.

Comment: how can i separate the div from the body then?

Comment: You can't, as the body is the outermost container of elements in an html document. You probably need to apply the blur effect to some other element, which is not an ancestor of the element you don't want to be blurred.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to apply the blur to everything inside the body, except the div itself.

```
$('body').children().not('div').toggleClass('blur');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zv8XX/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but couldn't you just add

`$('#DIV').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(0px)');`

(where #DIV is the div you don't want blurred) and turn off the blurring on that specific element?

Edit: They were saying in the above answer that it couldn't be done, so maybe something like a container for everything except the div?

http://jsbin.com/eDIPoYU/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this.

```
   $('#button').click(function(){
       $('body').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(4px)');
       $('body').find("div").css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(0px)');
    });
```